# percent sign in the legend of a bar chart using plotly in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I am using plotly package in R-Shiny to plot bar chart. The problem is that the percent sign  is not shown in the [image: legend].

The legend should be generated by using the following piece of code:

```
data1<- data[,list('MW (%)'=sum(as.numeric(Markw))/mw.g),by=Best]
data2<- data[,list('EL (%)'=sum(as.numeric(`EL absolut`))/EL.g),by=Best]
data3<- data[,list('VaR (%)'=sum(`VaR absolut`)/Var.g),by=Best]
.
.
.
```

I did not find any [option](https://plot.ly/r/reference/) to show **(%)** in the legend. I tried even the Unicode Character of %, however without success.
Any idea what could be the solution?

The whole code is really big and dose not really help to find the solution if one dose not know already the answer. Everyone can construct a minimal example in which one column is named:  'MW (%)' 
However, the part of plot in `server.R`

```
 output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    d.plot<-data.frame(dataset())
    # make traces:
    x<- d.plot[,1]
    y1<- d.plot[,2]*100
    y2<- d.plot[,3]*100
    y3<- d.plot[,4]*100

  #make the plot data frame:
    pl.d<- data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3)
  #define the margin
    m <- list(
      b = 200
      #autoexpand = TRUE
    )
  #plot
    plot_ly(pl.d, x = ~x, y = ~y1, type = 'bar', name = colnames(d.plot)[2], marker = list(color = "#26478A"),
            height=800) %>%
      add_trace(y = ~y2, name = colnames(d.plot)[3], marker = list(color = "#FF6600")) %>%
      add_trace(y = ~y3, name = colnames(d.plot)[4], marker = list(color = "#7E182F")) %>%
      layout("title" = colnames(d.plot)[1],
             xaxis = list(title = "", tickangle = 65,tickfont  = list(family= "Arial",size = 14),
                          margin = m
                          ), 
             yaxis = list(title = "",ticksuffix = "%"),
             barmode = 'group'
             #margin = m
             ) 
})
```

Comment: Could you provide the full code?

Comment: Please use the *r-plotly* tag instead of *plotly*.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check what is passed to the `name` arguement of `plot_ly` and `add_trace`:

```
library(plotly)

Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'MW (%)') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'EL (%)') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')

p
```

[image]

example [source](https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/#grouped-bar-chart)

*Edit:*
With the above example I wanted to point out, that this hasn't got to do anything with plotly.
The reason for the behaviour you describe is that the `data.frame()` function by default uses the `make.names()` function to check for syntactically valid names.
You can disable this option by setting `check.names=FALSE` in your call to `data.frame()`.

Please see the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame('MW (%)' = 1:10)
print(names(df1))
# [1] "MW...."

df2 <- data.frame('MW (%)' = 1:10, check.names=FALSE)
print(names(df2))
# [1] "MW (%)"
```

I hope this helped to clarify.

Comment: thanks a lot. your answer encouraged me to find the solution, however not the reason!

Answer (score 0):

actually I did not change the code  really. Because of the answer above, I recognized the problem lies on

```
d.plot<-data.frame(dataset())
```

I changed just for instance

```
name = colnames(d.plot)[2]
```

into

```
name = colnames(dataset())[2],
```

where `dataset()` is a `data.table`.

In other words,`data.frame` replacing by `data.table`